# jqueryUI autocomplete with Slim framework

Tags: jquery-ui, mod-rewrite, autocomplete, slim

I'm beginning with php, jquery and Slim PHP framework and I got stuck in making Slim handler (route) for jqeryUI autocomplete request.

1. jqeryui autocomplete sends data as a `term` GET parameter, i.e. `restapi.php/test/?term=hello`
2. with Slim I can handle requests like `restapi.php/test/hello`, etc.

How to solve? My own considered solution is to rewrite the URL with the mod-rewrite (anyway basically using it with the Slim), but I'm not sure if this is the right way.

I'll be glad for your revisions and suggestions and if rewriting is the best way, some references with examples will be helpful for me. Thank you.

Comment: I found easy way with default (Slim) mod_rewrite configuration.
Simply registering route with ending `/` or `/*` and reading GET request by classic way. I.e. `$rest->get('/test/*', function () {...`


_... I feel stupid now_

Comment: You can also solve this in the client side JS too. I can post an answer if you'd like to know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you probably shouldn't be using `/*` to do what you're doing. SLIM provides a method that can get the parameters of your request.

```
$dataIn = $app->request()->params();
```

This will give you an array of request parameters. So if your get request was something like this:

```
restapi.php/test/?term=hello&page=1&limit=15

$dataIn = $app->request()->params();

// $dataIn['term'] = 'hello'
// $dataIn['page'] = 1
// $dataIn['term'] = 15
```

Furthermore, you can grab specific parameters by throwing in an arg into the `param()` method.

```
$term = $app->request()->params('term');
```

It'll make life easier to have that distinction between your route parameters and request parameters. ;-)

Comment: yes, I found id too, but as I'm newbie here, I can't answer my question for couple of hours and then I forgot ...
my request registration is now something like this: `$app->get('/autocomplete/:handler/*', function ($handler) {...` and I'm passing `$_GET["term"]` to the handled function...